# Xampp Apache Wont start after wordpress installation

Tags: apache, xampp

I've been using Xampp for quite some time with no major hiccups. I attempted to make a local copy of one of my Wordpress sites. Seeing that Bitnami had an installer I attempted to use that. At the end of the installation it hung at maybe 5% left. So i cancelled and it supposedly cleaned up its files. Getting back into it today. Apache will not start. I have checked error logs and nothing seems to indicate what it actually is:

```
[Wed Sep 16 10:34:46.441511 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4424:tid 248] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 16 10:34:46.675505 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4424:tid 248] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 16 10:34:47.127893 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4424:tid 248] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 16 10:34:47.127893 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4424:tid 248] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Wed Sep 16 10:34:47.127893 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4424:tid 248] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Sep 16 10:34:47.127893 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4424:tid 248] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6624
[Wed Sep 16 10:34:47.985871 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 6624:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 16 10:34:48.251065 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 6624:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 16 10:34:48.313463 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6624:tid 260] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Wed Sep 16 10:39:12.205587 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 6860:tid 240] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 16 10:39:12.486382 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 6860:tid 240] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 16 10:39:12.533181 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6860:tid 240] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 16 10:39:12.533181 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6860:tid 240] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Wed Sep 16 10:39:12.533181 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6860:tid 240] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Sep 16 10:39:12.533181 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6860:tid 240] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7100
[Wed Sep 16 10:39:13.500362 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7100:tid 252] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 16 10:39:13.937154 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7100:tid 252] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 16 10:39:13.983953 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7100:tid 252] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I am not running IIS or Skype. Anyone have any ideas on what might be going wrong?

**EDIT:**

Should have mentioned. Nothing is listening on port 80 or 443. Also attempted to use other ports just in case. Still no dice.

Comment: Does it really say www.example.com in the errors, or have you changed that for display here?

Comment: It really says www.example.com.

Comment: In which case you've probably not configured the hostname correctly

Comment: Host shows 127.0.0.1 localhost and apache vhosts shows



##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright finally found my answer. After digging through Event viewer I found a syntax error in the httpd.conf file. Turns out as suspected Bitnami did not quite clean everything up as they had said. This was left behind and Xampp was unable to compile.

```
Include "C:/xampp/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```